# Implications of Encoding/Decoding and Encrypting/Decrypting with variable buffers

Tags: encryption, streaming, decode, encode

I have a program that **encrypts** and **decrypts** data using a symmetric key.

During the encryption process I:

- Encrypt the data
- ***Base64*** Encode it

During decryption:

- ***Base64*** decode it
- Decrypt the data

It works fine. Now I'm trying to do the process on a streaming buffer. Let's assume the encryption is done with the above-mentioned program on the bulk of the data and only the decryption happens whilst streamed.

In this scenario does the **buffer size**/**chunk-size** with which I encoded the data matter when I decode it?

As in if I encoded the data in buffers of 3000 bytes should I also read up to 3000 bytes and decode? Or is it that this doesn't matter?

Also when decrypting, should I ***decrypt*** using the same buffer-size I used to pass the data into the Cipher?

I tried with varying values with the standalone program and it works fine. However, when I try to do it streamingly:

1. Get some bytes
2. Decode it
3. Decrypt it
4. Save to file
5. For the next set of bytes decrypted keep appending to the same file.

This way it seems to work for some sizes of data and not for others. And the final size of the data is like lexx by **2-4 bytes**.

Am I missing some important principle here? Or is it that I might have made a mistake in the logic or a loop somewhere which causes some bytes being left out?

If it's the latter I will dig deeper to check it.

Thank You
Shabir

Comment: I don't know what your encryption algorithm is, but usually you require a [stream-cypher algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher) to properly perform encryption/decryption of streamed content.

Comment: *"As in if I encoded the data in buffers of 3000 bytes should I also read up to 3000 bytes and decode? Or is it that this doesn't matter?"* - It should not matter if it is properly implemented (with an internal "ring" buffer in case you choose a chunk size not divisible by 4).

Comment: With a buffer size of **3000** I checked the output of streamingly decoded bytes (by appending it to one file) and batch decoded bytes. They seem to be equal. However when I (decode + decrypt) and append to the file continuously, the final output is different from the batch decryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THanks for the hints above. I was able to solve the issue I had.

As mentioned in the comments above the buffer size itself did not matter much when **decoding** and **decrypting** the data as a stream.

However, the reason for the problem I had was because I was initializing the ***CipherOutputStream*** for every new chunk of incoming data.

Instead, when I initialized it once at the beginning only and maintained it for all the chunks of a single encrypted-data package, the flow worked as usual and without issue.

```
CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(byteArrOutputStream, cipher);
```

This was done once for all the chunks in the stream and it worked.

Thanks
Shabir